# Move an app to sd card

Tags: android, html, sd-card

I currently have an Android App "Gurbani Ujagar" in Playstore. I have over 1430 HTML files that loads on request and sometimes it takes more than 3-4 sec to load the file. I have received couple comments telling me to make it moveable to SD card. I am not quite sure how that would make any difference and how would I go on solving that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line to your `Manifest.xml` and everything works great:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

That means users can move the app to their sdcard/external storage and your app would prefer it to store your app their, **if available**.

Pretty simple and should solve your problem ;)

The difference:
your app does NOT consume valuable internalStorage (especially on older devices) and your users can save some space.

Comment: Could you expand on the "if available" part? Is this a carrier/phone maker choice? Is there a way to check if the device allows this programmaticaly?

Comment: "if available" depends on the android version. 2.2 and above use external, prior versions don't (cause they can't). You can check this programmatically by checking the sdk version of the device.

Comment: Thank you, but also on my newest device, a Samsung G3, version 4.1.2 (16) the app I wrote with android:installLocation="preferExternal" does not install in mnt/asec/ but rather goes into /data/app/... (it's a free app) versions 4.0(15) back to 2.2(8) seem to do as you mention.   Also, for my SG3, paid apps are all going into /mnt/asec/... I have been muddling thru all the changes going on with encryption of apps by Play store and wondering if you know if this is going to be standard operating procedure for Google from now .

Comment: Dont get confused with the data of an app and its install location. See http://cdn1.aptoide.com/imgs/e/7/7/e77bd15f9db0ced9f49dd376edd378e5.png ... its not about some folders on the sdcard, but more about where the system stores most of the app itself. It "may" be that google is able to chance sth (especially in paid apps) but the referece is really clear: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html Good Luck (btw: an upvote of my post would be great! ;) )

Answer (score 1):

As i can understand from what you say
You can try this(worked on my 4.1.2 android device):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ex"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" 
    android:installLocation="auto"> //Change to auto
```

Just change it to  `auto`and it will work fine
Sorry for my poor engish 
Best regards:)